Positive Harris recurrence and ergodicity for continuous time diffusion processes
For a diffusion process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ satisfying the usual conditions, we say that $X$ is Harris recurrent if, for a measurable set $A$, the first hitting time $\tau_A=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t\in A\}$ is so that $\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A<\infty)=1$ whenever $\varphi(A)>0$ for some $\sigma$-finite measure $\varphi$ (details can be found here). We say that $X$ is positive Harris recurrent if it is Harris recurrent and if the invariant measure is finite.
My question is, given that $X$ is a diffusion process, which satisfies quite a lot of restrictive yet nice and easy to work with properties, when can we say that positive recurrence equals ergodicity? Or are there positive recurrent but not ergodic processes? Additionally: can an ergodic process be not positive recurrent?
For the last question, I am pretty sure that any ergodic process must automatically be positive Harris recurrent, as ergodicity requires that the transition kernel $P_t$ is so that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\|P^t(x,\cdot)-\mu\|=0$ for all $x$ in which $\mu$ is the invariant probability measure (which is finite hence Positive recurrent)?
